# Passing Modbus TCP/IP nodes (connected in multiple VLANS, same network) via Toffino firewall

Tags: vlan, layer2

I have been assigned to check the security aspect of the below network shown in image.
When i asked question on security of individual modbus device, I was told to create individual `vlans` for each Modbus device and that shall suffice the security requirements.

But i feel this is not the correct method and below is myng (please correct me)

1. `vlans` are not a means for security
2. even if we create `vlans` with same network, control systems wont be able to communicate to the downstream devices due to `vlan id` in the `ethernet packet`. Can i simulate this in packet tracer (other than PCs and switches)

Please guide me.

[image: Required Network architecture]

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> vlans are not a means for security

VLANs *alone* are no means for security. Segregating hosts using VLANs *and controlling the traffic between them by firewalls* is.

> if we create vlans with same network, control systems wont be able to communicate to the downstream devices due to vlan id in the ethernet packet

That is the purpose of a VLAN in a data link layer (L2). It separates its traffic from the rest of the network.

Separating hosts in L2 means they can only communicate using the network layer (L3), forcing them to use gateways/routers. Those gateways are where you control the traffic. Of course, hosts in different VLANs also need to be in different IP subnets for routing to work.

If you require contiguous L2 connectivity then you cannot separate those hosts using VLANs. Modbus can run on top of TCP/IP, so it can be routed.

In your case, the Tofino firewall (or an additional router) needs to connect the separated IP subnets. Using firewall rules, you permit specific, required connections and deny all other traffic.

On the switch, create the required VLANs and assign device ports as untagged. Towards the firewall, define a VLAN trunk with all VLANs tagged.

On the firewall's trunk interface, create tagging VLAN subinterfaces and assign the IP subnets. The north-facing port towards the control systems uses yet another subnet.

Then you define the firewalls rules, e.g. allowing a specific control system access to a defined Modbus device or subnet.